# Entitty Framework outer join works until I add a where clause

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

This works:

```
  var query = from q in _context.Questions
                    join ua in _context.UserAnswers on q.ID equals ua.QuestionId
                    into temp
                    from ua in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new ProfileViewModel
                    {
                        Question = new Question { ID = q.ID, Text = q.Text },
                        Answer = (ua == null ? "" : ua.AnswerText)
                    };
```

I get a collection of FIVE blank userAnswer (there are FIVE questions) for the view. Great!

Now I need to add a condition to look for a specific user:

```
var query = from q in _context.Questions
                    join ua in _context.UserAnswers on q.ID equals ua.QuestionId
                    into temp
                    from ua in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where ua.User.Id == userId
                    select new ProfileViewModel
                    {
                        Question = new Question { ID = q.ID, Text = q.Text },
                        Answer = (ua == null ? "" : ua.AnswerText)
                    };
```

But now there are ZERO items in the collection instead of 5.

How do I get it to send my FIVE items like the first example ?

Comment: Don't you have `UserAnswers` collection navigation property in `Question`? By using explicit joins in EF query you are not using one of the best ORM features.

Comment: If `ua.User.Id` != `userId` why do you expect any items to come back? If you want `ua == null || ua.User.Id == userId` you should say so in the `where`.

Comment: What do you mean ? I could just dot navigate to get data instead of use joins ?